# Is there a way to find part of a css class within markup using Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Using Scrapy, is there a way to find a part of a class within the markup of a page, for example, if I have multiple classes such as "name-1, name-2, name-3", how can I find the base only? i.e. "name-"

Answer (score 3):

You can also apply "starts-with" checks in a pure XPath or CSS selector approach:

```
response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "name-")]')
response.css('[class^="name-"]')
```

Comment: Thank you for this, also. Question, If I were checking multiple domains and some had the classes that I was looking for and some didn't, is there a way to avoid the `list index out of range error` I seem to be getting that because in my list of URLs one or two don't have the classes I am attempting to scrape.

Comment: @Freddy well, the most "scrapic" approach would be to use a `TakeFirst` or `Join` processor defined on an item loader, see: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html.

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy selectors accept regular expressions, see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions

```
from scrapy import Selector
html = """
<a class="name-1" href="#">foo</a>
<a class="name-2" href="#">bar</a>
<a class="name-3" href="#">foo</a>
<a class="name-foo" href="#">teststr</a>
"""
sel = Selector(text=html, type="html")
print sel.xpath('//a[re:test(@class, "name-\d$")]').extract()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example and the resource link, much appreciated.

Comment: Just tried this out and worked like a charm...just starting out in Scrapy so thank you for getting me to the right resource for more information.

Comment: lazy css would be `sel.css([class^="name-"])`